# Get min and max time from date from multiple rows

Tags: mysql, sql

I have this table with following data.

```
Uid    date   time
1 2019-07-17   09:00:09
1 2019-07-17  17:30:32
1 2019-07-18   09:30:00
1 2019-07-19   09:14:23
1 2019-07-19   13:14;56
1 2019-07-19   17:34:22
```

I want to get these into following

```
1 2019-07-17 09:00:09 17:30:32
1 2019-07-18 09:30:00
1 2019-07-19 09:14:23 17:34:22
```

I am not good at SQL, so looking for the community help. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is basically aggregation.  A handy way to do this uses `nullif()`:

```
select uid, date, min(time), nullif(max(time), min(time))
from t
group by uid, date
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do this by grouping first by id and then date to get all unique records. Then you retrieve the min and max time values in the select statement.

```
SELECT uid, date, min(time), max(time)
FROM your_table
GROUP BY uid, date
```

Answer (score 0):

you could use min() max() and group  by check for min() and max()  not equal

```
select uid, date,  min(time) min_time
    , case when min(time) = max(time) then null else max(time) end  max_time
from my_table  
group by  uid, date
```